# Zend_Select select static value

Tags: zend-framework

How to make a request with the Zend_Select

```
SELECT "subdivision" as `type`, a.id as id FROM `some_table` a;
```

doing so

```
$ this-> select ()
-> from (
        array ('a' => 'some_table'), array ('type' => "subdivision", 'id' => 'a.id')
)
```

result

```
SELECT `a`. `" Subdivision "` as `type`, a.id as id FROM `some_table` a;
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to mark the static value so that `Zend_Db_Select` does not quote the value as an identifier using `Zend_Db_Expr`.

```
$this->select()
     ->from(array(
         'a' => 'some_table'
     ), array(
         'type' => new Zend_Db_Expr($db->quote('subdivision')), 
         'id'   => 'a.id'
     )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not always obvious but for Laminas it'll look like this

```php
$select->from(['a' => 'some_table'])
    ->columns([
        'id' => 'id',
        'type' => new Laminas\Db\Sql\Expression('"subdivision"')
    ]);
```